# Impossible for me to solve: Simple recursion does not take integers for indexing a list....source_sink does not exist?

Tags: prolog

This recursion should slice *IL* to *IR* out of the list *Lin* and hand result *LOut*...

```
slice(_,IL,IR,LOut) :-
    IR<IL,
    [LOut].
slice(Lin,IL,IR,LOut) :-
    nth0(IL,Lin,X),
    append(LOut,[X],LOut2),
    IK is IL + 1,
    slice(Lin,IK,IR,LOut2).
```

Input / Output:

```
?- slice([1,2,3,4],2,3,X).

ERROR: source_sink `'3'' does not exist
ERROR: source_sink `'4'' does not exist
X = [] .
```

I m also new to Prolog, but I think this recursion must somehow work. Also I'm not really known to the error codes in Prolog, but after checking multiple times I just have to give up... I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
slice(_,IL,IR,LOut) :-
    IR<IL,
    [LOut].    % <-- this line causes source_sink error.
```

That syntax `[name]` tries to load the file `name.pl` as Prolog source code. By the time your code gets there, `LOut` is `[3,4]` so it tries to load the files `3.pl` and `4.pl`, and they don't exist (thankfully, or else who knows what they could do).

---

> I think this recursion must somehow work

It won't; you are appending to a list as you go down into the recursion, which means you will never see the result.

The following might be a close version which works, at least one way:

```
slice(_,IL,IR,[]) :- 
    IR < IL.

slice(Lin,IL,IR,[X|LOut]) :- 
    IR >= IL,
    nth0(IL,Lin,X), 
    IK is IL + 1, 
    slice(Lin,IK,IR,LOut).


?- slice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 2, 5, X).
X = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

See how `[X|LOut]` in the second rule's header puts `X` in the result that you get, and `append/3` is not needed, and `LOut` finishes down in the recursion eventually as `[]` the empty list from the first rule, and all the `X`'s are prepended on the front of it to make the result on the way down into the recursion, which is *tail* recursion, so it doesn't need to go back up, only forward, since there's nothing left to be done after the recursive call.

Since the "`cons`" is done *before* the recursion, this is known as ["tail recursion *modulo cons*"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tailrecursion-modulo-cons/info) in other languages, but in Prolog it is just *tail*, and the list is being built top-down on the way forward, as opposed to being built bottom up on the way back:

```
Lin=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], slice( Lin, 2, 5, R)
:-
 nth0(2,Lin,X2), R=[X2|R2], slice( Lin, 3, 5, R2)
 :-
  nth0(3,Lin,X3), R2=[X3|R3], slice( Lin, 4, 5, R3)
  :-
   nth0(4,Lin,X4), R3=[X4|R4], slice( Lin, 5, 5, R4)
   :-
    nth0(5,Lin,X5), R4=[X5|R5], slice( Lin, 6, 5, R5)
    :-
     R5 = [].
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
list_elems_slice(Start, End, Lst, Slice) :-
    list_elems_slice_(Lst, 1, Start, End, Slice).

list_elems_slice_([H|T], N, N, End, [H|Slice]) :-
    list_elems_slice_capture_(T, N, End, Slice).
list_elems_slice_([_|T], N, Start, End, Slice) :-
    N1 is N + 1,
    list_elems_slice_(T, N1, Start, End, Slice).

list_elems_slice_capture_(_, N, N, []).
list_elems_slice_capture_([H|T], N, End, [H|Slice]) :-
    N1 is N + 1,
    list_elems_slice_capture_(T, N1, End, Slice).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- list_elems_slice(S, E, [a,b,c], Slice).
S = E, E = 1,
Slice = [a] ;
S = 1,
E = 2,
Slice = [a, b] ;
S = 1,
E = 3,
Slice = [a, b, c] ;
S = E, E = 2,
Slice = [b] ;
S = 2,
E = 3,
Slice = [b, c] ;
S = E, E = 3,
Slice = [c] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [findall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3 provides a readable readable solution for your problem:

```
slice(Lin,IL,IR,LOut) :-
  findall(E,(nth0(P,Lin,E),between(IL,IR,P)),LOut).
```

yields

```
?- slice([1,2,3,4],2,3,X).
X = [3, 4].
```

If you expect a different outcome, use standard arithmetic comparison operators ([=<](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3C)/2),[>=](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3E%3D)/2)) instead of [between](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)/3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the point of this exercise is to teach you to think recursively, I would approach the problem as follows.

To get what you want is essentially two separate operations:

- You first must ***discard*** some number of items from the beginning of the list, and then
- ***Take*** some number of items from what's left over

That gives us `discard/3`:

```
discard( Xs     , 0 , Xs ) .
discard( [_|Xs] , N , Ys ) :- N > 0 , N1 is N-1, discard(Xs,N1,Ys) .
```

and `take/3`, very nearly the same operation:

```
take( _      , 0 , []     ) .
take( [X|Xs] , N , [Y|Ys] ) :- N > 0 , N1 is N-1, take(Xs,N1,Ys) .
```

Once you have those two simple predicates, `slice/4` itself is pretty trivial:

```
%
% slice( List , Left, Right, Sublist )
%
slice( Xs, L, R, Ys ) :- % to slice a list,
    L =< R,              % - the left offset must first be less than or equal to the right offset
    N is R-L,            % - compute the number of items required, and then
    discard(Xs,L,X1),    % - discard the first L items, and
    take(X1,N,Ys).       % - take the next N items
    .                    % Easy!
```

Another approach would be to use `append/3`:

```
slice( Xs , L, R, Ys ) :-
  length(Pfx,L),          % - construct of list of the length to be discarded
  append(Pfx,Sfx,Xs),     % - use append to split Xs
  N is R-L,               % - compute the number of items required
  length(Ys,N),           % - ensure Ys is the required length
  append(Ys,_,Sfx)        % - use append to split off Ys
  .                       % Easy!
```